# TypeError: variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, settimeout

I am getting the following error : TypeError: slides[i] is undefined.

Its strange because shouldn't it be able to access the slides variable?

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getSlides.php",
            data: '',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response)
            {
                var slides = JSON.parse(response);
                for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if (slides[i].type === 'image') {
                            $('#slideshow').html('<img src="' + slides[i].image_video + '" />');
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `slides` variable is an array?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [classic closure in a loop problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getSlides.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(slides, function (slide) {
                if (slide.type === 'image') {
                    $('#slideshow').html('<img src="' + slide.image_video + '" />');
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could proxy your `sildes[i]` to `setTimeout` function callback, [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6MQp/1/) example

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getSlides.php",
        data: '',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var slides = JSON.parse(response);
            for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                setTimeout(function (slide) {
                    if (slide.type === 'image') {
                        $('#slideshow').html('<img src="' + slide.image_video + '" />');
                    }
                }, 2000, slides[i]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaking, this is a classic error, the setTimeout will execute async, after the loop has finished, so i should be equal to slides.length when the callback runs. To fix this, create a local scope for i, like this:

```
                for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                    (function(i){
                      setTimeout(function(callback) {
                        if (slides[i].type === 'image') {
                            $('#slideshow').html('<img src="' + slides[i].image_video + '" />');
                        }
                      }, 2000);
                    })(i)
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

because due to setTimeOut it calls your code after 2000ms, on that time value of i is slides.length for which it throw the error.

You have to arrange for a distinct copy of "i" to be present for each of the timeout functions.

```
 success: function (response) {
     var slides = JSON.parse(response);
     for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
         doSetTimeout(slides, i);

     }
 }

 function doSetTimeout(slides, i) {
     setTimeout(function () {
         if (slides[i].type === 'image') {
             $('#slideshow').html('<img src="' + slides[i].image_video + '" />');
         }
     }, 2000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace:

```
for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
```

to:

```
for (var i  in slides) {
```

Comment: What is the difference? If `slides` is an array, simple `for` loop *must* be used.

Comment: Do you sure that slides is array, not object?

Comment: [I am not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976568/typeerror-variable-is-undefined#comment29737428_19976568). However accidentally having an object with `length` property is rather doubtful.